# Run javascript function if option selected

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, html-select

If I have a select like this

```
<select id="selectid" name="selectname" onchange="jsfunc1()">
    <option value="val1" id="valid1"> Val1 </option>
    <option value="val2" id="valid2"> Val2 </option>
    <option value="val3" id="valid3"> Val3 </option>
</select>
```

I now have a javascript function `func2`, say, that need to do something if option `val1` is selected. How do I do that?

For example,

```
function func2(){
    ....
    if(document.getElementById('valid2').selected==True){
        //Do something 
    }
}
```

I'm not getting the exact syntax right and that's where I need your help.

Comment: Careful, case sensitivity, `True != true`.

Comment: `if(document.getElementById('selectid').value=='val1')`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I guess that this will work for you.

```
if(document.getElementById('selectid').value == "val1") {
     //Do something
}
```